# Sticky top menu with transparency (scroll only part of the document)

Tags: html, css, menu, transparency

I was creating a sticky menu on the top of the page setting it to a fixed position as usually.

Then I realized that it would be nice to see the picture in the background adjusting the opacity of the div.

There started to appear the problems due to when I scroll through the page all the text is displayed behind the div and I don't want that.

I was trying to figure out a way to scroll only a part of the page using overflow-y, but it needs a fixed height to work.

I'm stuck. Any suggestions?

This is the page where I'm working:

http://in2apps.com/nowa/

I need to scroll only the content-box div but I don't want to give it a fixed height.

The html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body style="background-image:url('img/1.jpg')">
        <div id="top-bar-box">
            <div id="top-bar">
                <div id="logo">
                    <a><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo"/></a>
                </div>
                <div id="top-menu">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content-box">
            <div id="content">
                <div class="icon"></div>
                <h1>Título Principal</h1>
                <h2>Título Secundario</h2>
                <h3>Subtítulo</h3>
                <p>... Text...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS of the DIVs:

```
#top-bar-box {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    color: #b20000;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

#top-bar {
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
}

#content-box {
    position: relative;
    top: 140px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

#content {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 940px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

**Edited:**

In this page you can see the result after the implementation of @AlienWebguy's solution.

http://in2apps.com/nowa/index4.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS**:

```
body {
    overflow : hidden;
}

content-box {
    overflow : scroll;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#content-box').css('height', ($(window).height() - 140) + 'px');
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I have already tested that combination. But the text is cut at the bottom of the page and the scroll does nothing, is disabled.

Comment: Right, you need to set the height if you're not doing it manually. See my edit. You'll want to put that into a function and bind it to the 'resize' window event. You can test it by adding it at the bottom of your script and it should work on load.

Comment: Thank you. That was the missing piece of the machine. Nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

Use this JQ plugin:

http://bigspotteddog.github.io/ScrollToFixed/

Then make a css class like this for example:

```
.filter.scroll-to-fixed-fixed {
background: #F2F4F5;
height: 65px;
padding-top: 20px;
}
```